# Angular 4: invoke method from template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Using Angular 4, I need to display the average of some numbers.  My component basically looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  students:string[];
  constructor(private studentsService: StudentsService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentsService.getStudents().subscribe(students => {
      ...
    })
    function doAvg (arr) {
      var i,
          len=arr.length,
          average=0,
          obj={};
      for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
         average += arr[i];
      }
      return (average/arr.length);
    }
  }
}
```

My template has this markup (GPARecord is an array of floats):

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
  ...
  <td>{{ doAvg(student.GPARecord) }}</td>
</tr>
```

But I'm getting this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.doAvg is not a function
```

Help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(i)You do not need to have the keyword **`function`**, also with ts, use **`let`** , instead of **`var`**

(ii)Move outside of **`ngOnInit()`**

```
  doAvg (arr) {
          let i,
          len=arr.length,
          average=0,
          obj={};
      for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
         average += arr[i];
      }
      return (average/arr.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined your function in the `ngOnInit()`. And also remove `function` word. Move out that function like

```
export class HomeComponent {
  students:string[];
  constructor(private studentsService: StudentsService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentsService.getStudents().subscribe(students => {
      ...
    });
  }

  doAvg (arr) : number {
      var i, len=arr.length, average=0,

      for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
         average += arr[i];
      }

      return (average/arr.length);
    }
}
```

You can also remove the `obj` variable from the function, because it is not used and make your function return type `number`.

Comment: thanks!  that works.  (Sajeetharan's answer had some extra info.)